# I'm Looking for a Well Sourced Article on this Argument About Old Testament Genealogy

Tags: exegesis, genesis, resource-request, genealogy

I remember reading a while back about how the ages in the Old Testaments first genealogy (leading up to Noah) were not representative of the actual ages of the individuals, but rather that this practice of high age was meant to show their level of greatness or honor. However I am unable to find any such article or paper, though I have heard the claim repeated on some YouTube videos. Can anyone help me find a well-sourced article or paper that talks about this idea? Thanks.

Comment: [This *Biologos* article](https://biologos.org/articles/long-life-spans-in-genesis-literal-or-symbolic) advanced a theory based on numerology, so does [this article](https://jonathanmclatchie.com/did-people-once-live-for-hundreds-of-years-evaluating-the-long-life-spans-of-genesis-5-11/) both referencing extra-biblical evidence in Ancient Near Eastern chronicles, although other meaning like you suggested is also plausible, just need to find a paper that supports it.

Comment: Possibly relevant – there are differences in ages of the patriarchs between the Septuagint, Masoretic, and Samaritan Old Testament texts, which might imply that accuracy of ages wasn't a primary concern for those who preserved the texts.